java-stripe version 26.0.0 is not able to deserializer event with api-version 2023-10-16
Using java-stripe version
implementation("com.stripe:stripe-java:26.0.0")

{
  "id": "evt_3PY5cgCeh1qdQtxa0SIqAQDf",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2023-10-16"
}

I am wondering why event.dataObjectDeserializer.`object` is empty

I was using older stripe-java version
24.16.0

implementation("com.stripe:stripe-java:24.16.0")

which was not deserializing "api_version": "2024-06-20"
{
  "id": "evt_3PYOb4EpyLlDkZVl1zL9TyCB",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2024-06-20"
}

so I upgraded stripe-java dependency to 26.0.0
implementation("com.stripe:stripe-java:26.0.0")

but now it's not deserializing "api_version": "2023-10-16"
{
  "id": "evt_3PY5cgCeh1qdQtxa0SIqAQDf",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2023-10-16"
}

Please advice.

stripe-java 26.0.0 is pinned to API version 2024-06-20 as mentioned here. So you need to make sure your webhook endpoint is sending events with version 2024-06-20, otherwise the events will fail to deserealize.
If you need help handling webhook versioning, follow these step-by-step instructions.
